# How to define an HDInsight hive external table based on XMLs in a container

Tags: hive, azure-hdinsight, external-tables

I tried creating a hive external table:

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TestXML (storexml string) 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'wasb:///test/';

However when i try executing query like below, its not able to extract the fields:
 SELECT 
        xpath_string (storexml, '/trades/trade/USI')

```
 FROM TestXML;
```

I saw a post, that talked about specifying the input format. 
add JARS <>
set xmlinput.element=Store;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EventStoreXML (storexml string) 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'msdn.hadoop.mapreduce.input.XmlElementStreamingInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' 
LOCATION 'wasb:///eventstore@tradedata.blob.core.windows.net/';

I could not determine, which jars to include in the add JARs statement. I am using HDInsight on Linux.

Any pointers will be appreciated.
-Madhu

Answer (score 0):

Realised the issue was with the XML having carriage return, as a result it was not able to read the XML.